# Relate users to items in a ManyToMany relation, what is best practice?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

In my Django project I have a model called Item, which basically stores a lot of items. I also make use of Django's built in User model to allow user's to register and login. What I now want is for each user to be able to check an item as "collected".

I'm not feeling comfortable in the way I've solved it right now, that's why I'm asking if this is good practice for this problem? Or is there any best practice to solve my problem?

This is my solution now:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Item(models.Model):
    ...
    users_collected = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='items_collected')
```

And I use this as: If there is a record between a user and an item, then the item is considered as collected by that user. To mark an item as collected I simply add a record, and to again mark it as not collected, I remove that record.
In my detail template for a specific item category I have the following code to display if a user has an item collected, or not.

```
{% for item in items %}
    {{ item.name }} - 
    {% if user in item.users_collected.all %}
        in collection.
    {% else %}
        not in collection.
    {% endif %}
```

My main concern using this method to solve the problem is the number of created and removed records for the ManyToMany-table that is created, as users will check and uncheck items regularly. I don't really like to put a new field to the Item's model either, as I guess it makes it less re-usable?

Comment: Could you expand on *I don't really like to put a new field to the Item's model either*? What field do you mean? I think you know this already, but `users_collected` is not an actual field on the `Item` table.

Comment: Yes, it's the users_collected I'm refering to. Does Django only create a new table, where it stores references to items and users, and then create relations from this table to the item's and user's tables?

Comment: Yes, exactly. `users_collected` will be an *attribute* on the model *instance*, created by Django for your convenience. It will not be a *field* on the database *table*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think this represents good practice. You need to persistently store the relationship between `Users` and `Items`, and your method does so in the most straightforward way possible.

A high database write rate can certainly be problematic, but how else would you store this information? One can imagine more exotic implementations, where, for example, each `User` has a bit-array field with one bit per `Item` indicating whether it is collected or not. But unless you have a good reason for doing something like that I would start with this straightforward approach.

One bit of advice I have is to make the M2M `through` table (see the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)) explicit. That will promote clarity, and make it easy to add any extra fields as the relationship becomes more complex.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When you say it like that, I guess it's hard to do it in any other way that is simple to implement. I will look at the M2M as well.